# No Boot Device Detected after Clear install of Ubuntu 15.10 dell latitude 6420

Tags: 14.04, dell

I Clean installed Ubuntu 15.10 on Dell Latitude 6420 on a new HDD, installation went OK with no errors, after that I get the GNU GRUB menu, and it Won't boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the GRUB boot loader - select the fitting version below.

**GRUB boot loader installation when the PC has a legacy BIOS**

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
On the Live desktop open a terminal.
Execute the following commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sd*
```

Note : `sd*` = disk | `sd**` = system partition

**GRUB boot loader installation when the PC has an UEFI BIOS**

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
On the Live desktop open a terminal.
Execute the following commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note : `sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use GParted ... it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: Thanks Cl-netbox, I don't know why when I installed 14.04 non of these issues happened. I will try now to dual boot my Dell XPS with the 14.04 I already reinstalled Win 10 on AHCI and UEFI. I really appreciate your patience and professionalism in dealing with this.